# How can I manipulate variable placeholders in PHP?

Tags: php

Without resorting to using regex, is there a way to do so if I saved my array into json format? I'm interesting in json only because I'm using mongodb so the output comes out in json format. I have a field called `docroot` which is essentially a directory path.

```
docroot : "secure.unstable.qa.example.com"
```

The only two pieces that could change depending on other factors are `unstable` and `qa.` What I'm hoping for is a way to place "markers" so that they could easily be replaced with an appropriate variable.

For example:

```
docroot : "secure.{STREAMS}.{ENV}.example.com"
docroot : "unsecure.{STREAMS}.{ENV}.example.com"
```

Comment: place markers as you said and then use str_replace?

Comment: sigh, been a long day. Thanks that was easy. What's the 'safest' marker to use?

Comment: use % or <> or any other sign instead of curly braces because JSON objects are written inside curly brackets.

Comment: `##STREAMS##` and `##ENV##` good enough?

Answer (score 0):

If the variables are guaranteed to be in some specific order (they are, according to your example), then I would advise [not reinventing the wheel](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
// Assuming $json contains your JSON

$streams = 'foo';
$env = 'bar';
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

var_dump($data['docroot']); // "secure.%s.%s.example.com"
var_dump(sprintf($data['docroot'], $streams, $env)); // "secure.foo.bar.example.com"
```

If the variables are not guaranteed, or you'd just like to use more descriptive placeholders, just pick some unique delimiters (some character or set of characters that is unlikely to actually appear in your data), and use [`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).